# Python dictionary switch goes through other functions instead of just the one called

Tags: python, function, math, dictionary, switch-statement

I'm making an extremely simple calculator style app where a control function is called with 5 parameters. The first one is a string that sets the mode for the calculator and the other 4 are numbers being used. I've used a dictionary to facilitate the switch between various modes.

However, it seems the application is checking all functions with the numbers instead of only the one I want. For example, if I use negative numbers in addition, I get math domain error in the square root function (that obviously cannot use negative numbers). Using normal positive numbers works without problems.

Thank you for any help or information about why this is happening and how to fix it.

Here is my primitive code:

```
import math

def control(a, x, y, z, k):
    return {
        'ADDITION': addition(x, y),
        'SUBTRACTION': subtraction(x, y),
        'MULTIPLICATION': multiplication(x, y),
        'DIVISION': division(x, y),
        'MOD': modulo(x, y),
        'SECONDPOWER': secondPower(x),
        'POWER': power(x, y),
        'SECONDRADIX': secondRadix(x),
        'MAGIC': magic(x, y, z, k)
    }[a]

def addition(x, y):
    return float(x) + float(y)

def subtraction(x, y):
    return float(x) - float(y)

def multiplication(x, y):
    return float(x) * float(y)

def division(x, y):
    return float(x) / float(y)

def modulo(x, y):
    return float(x) % float(y)

def secondPower(x):
    return math.pow(float(x),2.0)

def power(x, y):
    return math.pow(float(x),float(y))

def secondRadix(x):
    return math.sqrt(float(x))

def magic(x, y, z, k):
    l = float(x) + float(k)
    m = float(y) + float(z)
    return (l / m) + 1.0

a = input()
x = input()
y = input()
z = input()
k = input()

try:
    control(a, x, y, z, k)
except ValueError:
    print("This operation is not supported for given input parameters")

out = control(a, x, y, z, k)
print(out)
```

And this is the log:

```
C:\<path>\Python\Python35-32\python.exe C:/<path>/calculator.py
ADDITION
-6.0
5
3
2
This operation is not supported for given input parameters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/<path>/calculator.py", line 67, in <module>
    out = control(a, x, y, z, k)
  File "C:/<path>/calculator.py", line 13, in control
    'SECONDRADIX': secondRadix(x),
  File "C:/<path>/calculator.py", line 47, in secondRadix
    return math.sqrt(float(x))
ValueError: math domain error

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: So in your example, did you except the output to be -1.0, since your supplied the key 'ADDITION" and the first two numbers are -6.0 and 5, the issue is that you passed in a negative number as an input, you can't take the square of a negative number, and since your code is returning the dictionary you created, it's going to run each defined method, even if your just returning the value of one item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to delay evaluating your functions:

```
from functools import partial

def control(a, x, y, z, k):
    return {
        'ADDITION':       partial(addition, x, y),
        'SUBTRACTION':    partial(subtraction, x, y),
        'MULTIPLICATION': partial(multiplication, x, y),
        'DIVISION':       partial(division, x, y),
        'MOD':            partial(modulo, x, y),
        'SECONDPOWER':    partial(secondPower, x),
        'POWER':          partial(power, x, y),
        'SECONDRADIX':    partial(secondRadix, x),
        'MAGIC':          partial(magic, x, y, z, k)
    }[a]()
```

It is inefficient to create curried functions on each call to `control` so here is a second approach that creates your dictionary only once:

```
def control(a, x, y, z, k):
    return control.funcs[a](x, y, z, k)
control.funcs = {
    'ADDITION':       (lambda x, y, z, k: addition(x, y)),
    'SUBTRACTION':    (lambda x, y, z, k: subtraction(x, y)),
    'MULTIPLICATION': (lambda x, y, z, k: multiplication(x, y)),
    'DIVISION':       (lambda x, y, z, k: division(x, y)),
    'MOD':            (lambda x, y, z, k: modulo(x, y)),
    'SECONDPOWER':    (lambda x, y, z, k: secondPower(x)),
    'POWER':          (lambda x, y, z, k: power(x, y)),
    'SECONDRADIX':    (lambda x, y, z, k: secondRadix(x)),
    'MAGIC':          (lambda x, y, z, k: magic(x, y, z, k))
}
```

At this point it may be simpler do away with the `control` function and just use the dictionary directly.

Comment: Is there a benefit to using partials over lambdas in this case? We're not too interested in currying, so it might be easier (but not necessarily cleaner) to use lambdas

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee:  I considered lambas, but I think they would be too verbose.

Comment: Since you were concerned about creating the partials and dict every time, you could also just bind them to control (not sure if good idea, just works though). Python's lack of C-style statics is a bit annoying in this case.

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee:  I added a variation that does just that.

Comment: This worked for me perfectly. Thank you for all the other replies as well. I assumed it was calling all the functions but wasn't sure why and how to deal with it (without resorting to `if-elif-elif` structure).

Comment: @StevenRumbalski it seems like you have a few typos in the second version (parentheses are confusing :P)

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee:  Whoops.  That was atrocious.  Fixed now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is rewrite the code, it is more code, but it is easier to maintain and you won't run all the methods, only the one you want since it seems you were just returning the single key anyway. If you want to run more then one operation, then pass in the operations as a string e.g, a = input() --> "ADDITION SUBTRACTION", then split(" ") to create a list.  Iterate over that list and pass a into the method control.

```
import math

def control(a, x, y, z, k):
    if a == 'ADDITION':
        return addition(x, y)
    elif a == 'SUBTRACTION':
        return subtraction(x, y)
    elif a == 'MULTIPLICATION':
        return multiplication(x, y)
    elif a == 'DIVISION':
        return division(x, y),
    elif a == 'MOD':
        return  modulo(x, y)
    elif a == 'SECONDPOWER':
        return secondPower(x)
    elif a == 'POWER':
        return power(x, y)
    elif a == 'SECONDRADIX':
        return secondRadix(x)
    elif a == 'MAGIC':
        return magic(x, y, z, k)
```

Comment: I agree that the simplest approach is probably best.  In my answer `partial` is called on every possible function.  Here the comparison is made more than once, but it still wins out over the multiple function calls.

Comment: You can still dispatch without the overhead and without `if-elif-elif-...` block, which I really struggle with stylistically.

Comment: I could, and yes, it isn't pretty, but if the OP want's something that works now, there it is, I follow the get it to work, then break it later process lol.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski better?

Comment: Great Feedback. This is definitely more readable when, and useful when you are just starting out. If you are working on a prototype or a problem set. But if you want this to be apart of an enterprise or real solution then there must be an optimum solution in place,

Answer (score 0):

When you pass all the arguments to `control`, each individual function is evaluated since you have parens appended to it. You end up trying to calculate `math.sqrt(float(-6))` which is an imaginary number. In order to avoid this, you would have to design control with a generic `*args` such as

```
def control(a, *args):
    return {
        'ADDITION': addition,
        'SUBTRACTION': subtraction,
        'MULTIPLICATION': multiplication,
        'DIVISION': division,
        'MOD': modulo,
        'SECONDPOWER': secondPower,
        'POWER': power,
        'SECONDRADIX': secondRadix,
        'MAGIC': magic
    }[a](*args)
```

Which allows you to retrieve the *one* function you are interested in and then call it with your arguments.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a bit more complicated than this as this will generate errors on the called functions, because you pass too many variables, e.g. `addition(*args)` -> `addition(x,y,z,k)` is an error.

Comment: That is true, the OP must pass only the required arguments, or define how many he needs and throw the rest away, like `def secondRadix(x, *args)`

Comment: You could hold the number of args in the dispatch dictionary too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a great fan of big `if-elif-elif-else` but understand the need to avoid constructing the dictionary every time.
Expanding on @C.B.'s answer - you can still use a dictionary  dispatch mechanism but just store the function and number of arguments in the dictionary.
This can now be created once outside of the function, e.g.:

```
dispatch = {
    'ADDITION': (addition, 2),
    'SUBTRACTION': (subtraction, 2),
    'MULTIPLICATION': (multiplication, 2),
    'DIVISION': (division, 2),
    'MOD': (modulo, 2),
    'SECONDPOWER': (secondPower, 1),
    'POWER': (power, 2),
    'SECONDRADIX': (secondRadix, 1),
    'MAGIC': (magic, 4)
}

def control(a, *args):
    func, count = dispatch[a] 
    return func(*args[:count])
```